# Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri and Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration'

Tags: jhipster, okta

I created a new jhipster monolothic application, and it works fine. But when I try jhipster with okta it fails and I get error messages. With okta I cannot start jhipster on a default scaffold.

I feel like I have tried hard to get this problem resolved and have not found a solution. I tried it under java 8, 11 and 12 and still had the same issue. I checked over my okta and application configs pretty well. Please advise me of common or potential resolution if possible. I tried overriding the configs and everything.

bflew

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri' in value "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri}"
>
> Expected result shoul be okta running with jhipster application. There is no scaffold system with jhipster currently for orka.

Hey, I do have this added and it still doesnt work  spring:

````
application:
   name: ServerBirdTheatre
 profiles:
   # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.
   # Otherwise, it will be filled in by maven when building the JAR file
   # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
   active: #spring.profiles.active#
 jmx:
   enabled: false
 data:
   jpa:
     repositories:
       bootstrap-mode: deferred
 jpa:
   open-in-view: false
   properties:
     hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
   hibernate:
     ddl-auto: none
     naming:
       physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
       implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
 messages:
   basename: i18n/messages
 main:
   allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
 mvc:
   favicon:
     enabled: false
 task:
   execution:
     thread-name-prefix: server-bird-theatre-task-
     pool:
       core-size: 2
       max-size: 50
       queue-capacity: 10000
   scheduling:
     thread-name-prefix: server-bird-theatre-scheduling-
     pool:
       size: 2
 thymeleaf:
   mode: HTML
security:
 oauth2:
   client:
     provider:
       oidc:
         issuer-uri: https://***.okta.com/oauth2/default
     registration:
       oidc:
         client-id: ***
         client-secret: *** ```
I changed the key so i didnt broadcast it publicly, but that is the config and it throws the error.
````

Comment: if you give that `issuer-uri` configuration a non-wildcard value, does it affect your error message?

Comment: no im saying I added *** so i dont expose my key, im saying the error is when it has correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Your `application.yml` should have something like the following configuration in it:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://dev-737523.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: 0oafx05pu2pxhjgkC0h7 
            client-secret: ozxBeuk7nE-oLhkUvINe1cxR3LITquTp7Jt2NvX7
```

I'm guessing you still have `{}` or `${}` placeholders. See https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/04/java-11-java-12-jhipster-oidc for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out kind of I guess. I cleaned and rebuilt my whole environment, Then made sure my configs are exactly as shown and the application has started running java open jdk 11. however now I get invalid_id_token when trying to login, but the app does start up now, but login page is broken.

```
   security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://dev-992900.okta.com/oauth2/default
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: yourclientid
            client-secret: yoursecretkey
```

Comment: its still not working, ive basically given up using okta for my web app.